# Octave with gnuplot adds edges in a mesh

Tags: gnuplot, octave

When doing `surf` in octave I get the following results, with different `graphics_toolkit`.

---

*Run:*

`surf([1 2 ; 1 2 ],[1 1; 2 2],[6 2 ;4 6],'FaceColor','interp')`

*To change graphics toolkit you may need to restart octave and run:*

`graphics_toolkit ftlt|gnuplot`

---

I want `gnuplot` (B) to display edges as in `fltk` (A). For some reason I dont understand, gnuplot adds a lot of edges in the middle of the plotted faces (B) which I want to remove.

Using `'EdgeColor','none'` (C) I'm able to remove all edges, although I want to keep the edges between datapoints (ie, those shown in A).

An option would be to use `fltk`, but I prefer the presentation (coulouring and shape) and latex support `gnuplot` provides.

*So: How to make gnuplot show **only** the edges between datapoints (ie. those in A)??*

**A) Using default fltk:**
[image: Using default fltk]

**B) Using gnuplot:**
[image: Using gnuplot]

**C) Using gnuplot with 'EdgeColor','none'**
[image: Using gnuplot with 'EdgeColor','none']

Comment: Are all matrices 6x6? Is it correct that your question is: "How can I get the plots shown in A, but with the possibility of using Latex markup?"

Comment: No, my goal is not related to latex markup: the colouring done by fltk is wrong, so I want to use gnuplot. All I need is to remove the black extra edges

Comment: [mvce](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: All matrices are 6x6 although I think the solution should work for any number of elements

Comment: @ederag just do this:

`surf([1 2 ; 1 2 ],[1 1; 2 2],[6 2 ;4 6],'FaceColor','interp')`

if you use gnuplot you will see _one_ edge made up of two lines
if you use ftlt you will see it cluttered with edges

to change graphics toolkit you may need to restart octave and run:
`graphics_toolkit ftlt|gnuplot`

Comment: @AndresR confirmed. It is even worse (almost all black) with the development version [cs 21674:5e083d07ba35]. Under linux, with either `gnuplot 4.6 patchlevel 6` or `gnuplot 5.0 patchlevel 1`. [Search](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?func=search&group=octave) then [file bug report](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?func=additem&group=octave) ?